# How to fire "Click" event of Checkbox using "Label Click" event in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

In my Delphi XE2 Project, I am having `Form1`, `Label1` and `CheckBox1`.

My requirement is to set the `CheckBox1.Font.Color := clGreen;`.

Thought I have written

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckBox1.Font.Color := clGreen;
end;
```

yet the `Font Color` is default `Black`. So I have defined it in other way as follows:

1. I have removed the `Caption` from the `CheckBox1` and changed the `Width` to `17`.
2. Then I have placed `Label1` next to `CheckBox1` like `CleckBox1 Caption`.
3. After that I have written:

```
procedure TForm1.Label1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckBox1.Click;
end;
```

to `Toggle` the state of `CheckBox1`.

But I am getting `[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(37): E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TCustomCheckBox.Click`.

And another question is that whether the `OnMouseDown Event` of `CheckBox1` can be triggered as the following image:
[image: Form1]

Comment: Please ask a question for each topic, don't add more question to the original question ...

Comment: First question: the 'Click' method is protected, hence the error.

Comment: Have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 5):

The `Click()` method merely triggers the contro's `OnClick` event, nothing else. It does not actually cause the control to perform click-related logic, like updating its internal state.

You can toggle the CheckBox's state like this:

```
CheckBox1.Checked := not CheckBox1.Checked;
```

Alternatively, use an accessor class to reach protected members:

```
type
  TCheckBoxAccess = class(TCheckBox)
  end;
```

```
TCheckBoxAccess(CheckBox1).Toggle;
```

Comment: You have told that it merely triggers `CheckBox1` `OnClick` event, how to avoid it? I have to perform some calculation based on the `Click Logic` (i.e. some Edits will be enabled and disabled according to `CheckBox1 Click` and they will perform major part of my calculation.

Comment: @user - Toggling the check box will fire its OnClick event handler, you can keep your code there.

Comment: @User YOU ARE DOING IT WRONG.  Change your OnClick event to just call a function named `DoSomething`. Now call `DoSomething`.  Except, call it something that makes sense. Remember that you will hate yourself later for doing dumb things like this now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like :

```
procedure TForm1.Label1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//either
CheckBox1.Checked := not CheckBox1.Checked;  // this trigger onClick event!!
// or 
// if you absolutely need it.. 
CheckBox1Click(Sender); // NOTE this will not check or uncheck CheckBox1
end;
```

But note you use here a TLabel Object (Sender). If you do not use `Sender` you can do it Without further attention.

But it's better to put the code for enable and disable other control out of the event. only one line for example doenable() .

```
procedure TForm1.doEnable(enable: Boolean);
begin
  Edit1.Enabled := enable; 
  Edit2.Enabled := enable;
  Edit3.Enabled :=  NOT enable;
  if enable then Label1.Font.Color := clGreen else Label1.Font.Color := clWindowText;
  ...
end;


procedure TForm1.Label1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // NOTE This trigger also CheckBox1 Click event. 
  CheckBox1.Checked := not CheckBox1.Checked; 
  // NOT needed.
  //if CheckBox1.Checked then doEnable(true) else doEnable(false);
end;

procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked then doEnable(true) else doEnable(false);
end;
```